# How do you show loading in ionic view or load all of app at once in cache/memory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show a loading animation (basic circular animation that is built in to ionic) to load a tab. I have tried $ionicLoading and I can get it to work for my splash screen but I am having trouble incorporating it for individual view. I want the tabs bar to remain visible while the loading animation is there but have the actual view be hidden.

I have code for the splash screen loading here:

```
angular.module('LoadingApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('LoadingCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.show = function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Loading...',
            noBackdrop: 'true',
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
        });
    };
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide().then(function () {
            console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
        });
    };
})
```

and I tried to use that in a similar manner inside a view but nothing appears. How do I use that code in a view. Alternatively, is there a way to load everything in the app into cache/ram so that there is no lag time between clicking different tabs. Some of my tabs have images that take a while and pop in after the text.

Comment: You can listen for these [view events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) but you'll be notified when html file of the view is loaded. Loading of html file of the view is separate than content of the view and images are part of content. You can create a preloader service and use it to load images when you navigate to the controller, show preloader until images are loaded and hide when all images are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/

This `<ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>` show an animated spinner.

You can use a boolean "LoadingView" to show/hide the spinner. Example:

```
<ion-spinner ng-show="LoadingView" icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>
<div ng-show="!LoadingView" icon="spiral">Content of the tab</div>
```

Initialise the boolean on false, and when the page finish to loading the elements you can switch to on, to show your tab content

Comment: how do you switch the boolean when the page is loaded? Is there a $on('pageloaded') function